# Parameter value [....] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-boot-jpa

I am using `spring-boot`, `spring-data-JPA` and `Hibernate` and I've a `Form Entity` and a `Group Entity` and they have a `@ManyToMany` relationship between them.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "form_group",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name = "form_id", referencedColumnName = "id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "group_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    @JsonIgnore
    private Collection<Group> groups;
```

In `FormRepository` class I have a method called 
`public List<Form> findByGroups(Collection<Group> userGroups);` which takes a parameter of type `Collection<Group>` and is expected to return all the forms which belong to at least one of the  groups passed as the method parameter. Here is the Query:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.nsia.model.Form(f.id, f.name, f.description, f.createdAt, f.groups, COUNT(i.id)) from Form f LEFT JOIN f.instances i WHERE f.groups IN (?1) group by f.id")
```

As you can see the `userGroups` is of type `Collection<Group>` and inside the `Form Entity` it is of the same type. When the method `findByGroup`is called, it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` and here is the full message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [Group {id=4, name='DATA_ENTRY_GROUP', description='DATA ENTRY GROUP'}] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
```

I'm sure that `userGroups` is of type `Collection<Group>` because here is how i'm getting it inside the `FormServiceImpl` class:

```
        Collection<Group> groups = userService.getLoggedInUser().getGroups();
        formsList = formRepository.findByGroups(groups);
```

There are lots of similar questions in StackOverflow and I've tried every one of them and none worked for me, any help will be highly appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying is not possible.

The constructor expression cannot take a collection as an argument because the result of the under laying SQL select statement is always a table.

So the only thing you can do is to get a cartesian product back like this where you join f.groups.

```
@Query("SELECT new com.nsia.model.Form(f.id, f.name, f.description, f.createdAt, g, COUNT(i.id)) from Form f LEFT JOIN f.instances JOIN f.groups g WHERE f.groups IN (?1) group by f.id")
```

So you will get a record per group but that's probably not what you want.

Comment: Dear @Simon! THANK YOU for your answer, however, it does not work for me, I tried it and it throws NoViableAltException and says:  unexpected token: i.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo in my answer. Please try again.

Comment: Dear @Simon! thank you for bearing with me. Unfortunately, your edited answer also does not work for me. I've literally tried every variation of it and none of them worked. I also wrote the results of each variation of the code in the previous comment, some of which was compile time errors and some with the original problem and for some reason i lost it and couldn't deliver to you. :)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thank you for this answer, it worked for me with:

`@Query("SELECT df FROM DeskFloor df LEFT JOIN df.spaces s WHERE s.id = ?1")`